# Using lapply to extract Pvalue from an ADF Test in R

Tags: r

This is my list:

```
mylist=dput(mylist)
list(list(c(30, 50, 35, 25, 45), c(40, 35, 35, 50, 45), c(40, 
20, 40, 50, 25), c(35, 45, 45, 45, 40), c(20, 30, 50, 45, 20), 
    c(40, 40, 50, 30, 40)), list(c(50, 50, 25, 40, 45, 40, 35, 
40, 45, 20), c(40, 35, 40, 40, 45, 30, 20, 50, 35, 25), c(20, 
30, 50, 35, 45, 40, 25, 50, 35, 50), c(20, 35, 30, 25, 40, 30, 
50, 20, 25, 35), c(40, 25, 25, 20, 50, 30, 50, 40, 35, 35), c(50, 
20, 45, 35, 50, 45, 30, 45, 35, 50)), list(c(45, 50, 25, 25, 
30, 25, 35, 35, 35, 30, 50, 50, 30, 30, 20), c(40, 20, 35, 35, 
50, 20, 25, 30, 35, 20, 40, 20, 45, 30, 20), c(50, 20, 25, 35, 
35, 30, 50, 25, 40, 35, 45, 45, 35, 45, 25), c(50, 50, 25, 35, 
25, 35, 20, 25, 45, 40, 35, 40, 50, 40, 30), c(50, 25, 20, 30, 
40, 45, 40, 50, 35, 40, 30, 45, 35, 50, 40), c(35, 50, 35, 45, 
25, 40, 50, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 35, 35, 40)), list(c(50, 50, 
50, 40, 20, 25, 50, 40, 50, 50, 45, 40, 30, 50, 35, 45, 50, 30, 
35, 45), c(45, 20, 25, 20, 25, 30, 20, 30, 45, 25, 50, 30, 30, 
25, 50, 45, 20, 45, 45, 50), c(20, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 25, 30, 
20, 20, 35, 45, 20, 40, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 35), c(40, 40, 20, 
25, 50, 50, 35, 45, 50, 45, 50, 35, 30, 40, 35, 45, 25, 45, 45, 
25), c(20, 25, 35, 45, 35, 40, 40, 35, 35, 40, 30, 30, 40, 50, 
25, 40, 30, 25, 20, 40)), list(c(35, 25, 45, 20, 25, 30, 30, 
35, 30, 40, 30, 20, 20, 30, 45, 40, 35, 35, 35, 35, 25, 45, 35, 
20, 50), c(50, 35, 30, 30, 35, 45, 45, 50, 25, 25, 40, 25, 50, 
45, 25, 30, 30, 25, 45, 45, 30, 20, 50, 30, 30), c(35, 40, 50, 
25, 40, 45, 30, 25, 50, 25, 35, 50, 50, 50, 25, 50, 20, 50, 40, 
25, 25, 35, 20, 20, 50), c(40, 35, 35, 40, 50, 35, 25, 40, 25, 
25, 30, 45, 50, 35, 20, 50, 20, 20, 45, 50, 40, 30, 35, 50, 45
), c(40, 25, 50, 50, 20, 50, 25, 50, 40, 30, 30, 50, 45, 45, 
40, 45, 20, 20, 45, 35, 45, 50, 40, 40, 35), c(40, 45, 35, 35, 
30, 45, 40, 40, 20, 50, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 45, 35, 40, 20, 30, 
35, 45, 30, 50, 25)))
```

In each `mylist[[1]][[1]],mylist[[1]][[2]],mylist[[3]][[1]],mylist[[1]][[4]],mylist[[1]][[5]],mylist[[1]][[6]]` (Until the `mylist[[5]][[6]]` position) position I would like to run a ADF test and extract its pvalue using Lapply function.

For this purpose I create a result list and run the code below:

```
resultlist<-vector(mode = "list", 5)
# library(  _enter_name_of_package )
resultlist <- lapply(mylist, 
                function(x) 
                lapply(x, function(y) rep(adf.test(mylist)$p.value(y), length(y))))
```

It is not working. It would be fundamental mantain the lapply structure code like above.

I was able to extract the mean by doing this (even giving me repeated values, this is not a problem)

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) rep(mean(y), length(y))))
```

With this code in mind I want to run the ADF test and extract the pvalue.

Comment: Please re-read the help page. The p.values are one the third matrix column of the various lists: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aTSA/versions/3.1.2/topics/adf.test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you want to apply a function (here `myfun`) to each element of a list-of-lists (here `mylist`), then do this:

```
lapply(mylist, lapply, myfun)
```

This will return a list-of-lists result, which you can convert into a vector with `unlist`.

I'm not sure which `adf.test` function you're using for your specific application, as there is a function by this name in both the `tseries` and `aTSA` packages (and maybe others). Regardless, a solution will look something like this:

```
lapply(mylist, lapply, function(x) adf.test(x)$p.value)
```